# How can i increase the choice of 2 numbers by a percentage?

Tags: python, random, percentage

So i have a code that choses a random number  between 1 and 2. If the code choses 1, i want  to increase the choice of 1 y 10%. If the code choses 2, want  to increase the choice of 2 15%.
Here is my code :

```
import pygame, random,sys

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500
BLACK = (0,0,0)
white = "#FFFFFF"
win = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")


def test2():
    win.fill(BLACK)
    
    test = random.randint(1,2) 
    text_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    screws_text = text_font.render(str(test), True ,white)
    textRect = screws_text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (250,250)
    win.blit(screws_text, textRect)
    
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit() 
    pygame.display.update()
        

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                test2()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I didn't really tried anything because i have no idea that i should do, i never did that so i would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: What does "increase the choice" mean?

Comment: If you increase a number between 0 and 1 by either 10% or 15% then it need not stay within the interval 0 to 1. Simple numerical experiments show that your idea rapidly leads to "probabilities" that are not probabilities at all (assuming that by "increase the choice" you meant "increase the probability of choosing").

Answer (score 0):

You can't always increase a probability by 10% or 15% and have it remain a probability, but you can do so if you are willing to cap the probability at 1. The following code implements a generator (with a starting probability of 1 given by the parameter `p`). With each successive number yielded, the probabilities of 1 and 2 are adjusted:

```
import random

def pick_nums(p = 0.5):
    q = 1 - p
    while True:
        num = 1 if random.random() < p else 2
        if num == 1:
            p = min(1, 1.1*p)
            q = 1 - p
        else:
            q = min(1, 1.15*q)
            p = 1 - q
        yield num

#test

for _ in range(5):
    nums = pick_nums()
    print(*(next(nums) for _ in range(20)))
```

Typical test output:

```
2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

As you can see, the output becomes all 1 or 2 after relatively few iterations, with the output becoming all 2 more often than it becoming all 1.